# How to retrivew elements of an Array of unkown size in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have created an app which will find the common factors of 2 or more numbers entered by the user. I have used a single Edit Text field to get user input. Different numbers are separated by comma (,). All the numbers are stored in an array.
My question is that how can I access the elements of the array of n size. Following is the code. I want to find the factors of all the user entered numbers. I can find the the factors of integernumbers[0] index but after that the code thorws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
             int factors1 = 0;
            int factors12 = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String value = edtCommonFact.getText().toString()
                String[] stringsNumber = value.split(",");
                Integer[] integersNumbers = new Integer[stringsNumber.length];
                for (int i = 0; i<stringsNumber.length; i++){
                    integersNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringsNumber[i]);
                }
                Arrays.sort(integersNumbers);
                for (int i = 1; i<=integersNumbers[0]; i++){
                    if (integersNumbers[0]%i == 0){
                        factors1 = i;
                        sb.append(factors1).append(" ");
                 for (int j = 1; j<=integersNumbers.length; j++){
                     if (integersNumbers[j]%j == 0){
                         factors12 = j;
                         sb.append(factors12).append(" ");
                     }
                 }
                        }

                }
           String result = sb.toString();
            commonFactResult.setText("Common factors are: " + result);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use ArrayList instead of Array.

Comment: Could you please explain with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` because not like an `array` it doesn't need a size declaration. As an example if we wants an `String` array with size 10 we need to declare it as

```
String[] s = new String[10]
```

but in `ArrayLists` you can define the `ArrayList` and use it for any no of items.

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>()
```